# Python: trying to write dataframe to influxdb and receive the message "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, indexing, influxdb, bucket

I'm trying to mimic what is done here (python, influxdb, yfinance (vs googlefinance), and eventually graphana)).  I finally figured out how to use buckets vs the database method described in the following two tutorials

https://frobots.net/post/2016-03-01/monitoring-stocks-with-grafana

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/watch-your-stock-shares-with-grafana-and-influxdb-4df7a99c6d64

Trying to follow influxdb 2.0 API instructions here

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python#how-to-use-jupyter-pandas-influxdb-2

https://pypi.org/project/influxdb-client/

I merged my list into a dataframe and added a Date and Symbols column (the methods above used json files without giving me proper examples... and yfinance doesn't give me a json.  It gives me a dataframe and I only have a single bucket so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to write each stock as a separate dataframe, so I merged them into a single dataframe adding a symbol column.  This threw my index off as the index was dates, so I created a new index).  I had success when I wrote each dataframe (with it's resulting date as index)... but I'm afraid I'm just writing over the same data with each stock.  So I merged the stocks into a giant dataframe adding a date and symbols column (demoralizing the table a bit).

```
df = pd.concat(self.stock_prices, ignore_index=True)
```

What I'm trying to do is download a # of stocks (10 in this example), and then upload it to the bucket so I can eventually graph it.  I'm not sure if I should be doing it the way I'm doing now, or some other method (I would think I'd want to write a new table per stock but the examples I have w buckets don't show me how to specify a table. I believe I saw such methods for api 1.8 [Write pandas DF with tags to influxdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506670/write-pandas-df-with-tags-to-influxdb) vs https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-with-influxdb-and-pandas/). Right now I seem to be stuck on the index

```
_now = df.index
```

which appears right, but if I do a print(df.index).  nothing shows up.  But if I do a len(df.index) it shows correctly. If I try to opt for a manual index...

```
_now = list(range(0,len(df.index),1))
```

I get the same error

Here is my code

```
import concurrent.futures
import json
import time, random
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import urllib.request
import influxdb_client
import numpy as np
from numpy import inf
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

start="2017-01-01"
end="2020-04-30"

nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
trading_dates= nyse.schedule(start_date=start, end_date=end)
idx2 = trading_dates.index

influx_bucket = "local"
influx_org = "localdomain"
influx_token = "H60IaJ-9t64Zws296bpkJZNIu7ylUbJxfD6RH-thenW2cvWgxXUpADJN1R4o9PsiUtZAE7KjuK0Wzcu_DypdbQ=="
# Store the URL of your InfluxDB instance
influx_url="http://192.168.3.114:8086"

client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(
    url=influx_url,
    token=influx_token,
    org=influx_org
)

write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)

url = 'ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'nasdaqtraded.txt')
df = pd.read_csv('nasdaqtraded.txt', sep='|')
size=10
symbols = df["Symbol"][0:-1].sample(n=size)

class Stocks():
    def __init__(self, db="stocks", stocks_file="stocks.json"):
        self.stocks=None
        self.db=db
        self.stock_prices = list()
        #column_names = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Dividends", "Stock Splits", "Symbol"]

        #df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)        
        #self.load_stocks_from_json(stocks_file)
        self.stocks=symbols
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for out1 in executor.map(self.dl_stocks, self.stocks):            
                self.stock_prices.append(out1)                
        
    def load_stocks_from_json(self, stocks_file):
        with open(stocks_file) as f:
            data=json.load(f)
            self.stocks=data['stocks'] 
            
    def dl_stocks(self, stock):
        ticker = yf.Ticker(stock)
        _data_frame = ticker.history(start=start, end=end, interval="1d", auto_adjust=True)
        #history = ticker.history()
        #last_quote = (history.tail(1)['Close'].iloc[0])
    
        idx1 = _data_frame.index  
        
        merged = idx1.union(idx2)
        s = _data_frame.reindex(merged)
        #s['New_Price'] = (1/s['Stock Splits']).replace(inf,1).cumprod() * s['Close']
        df = s.interpolate()  
        df['Symbol'] = stock
        df['Date'] = s.index
        
        return (df)
    
    def print_stocks(self):
        print(self.stock_prices) 
        
    def write_db(self):
        df = pd.concat(self.stock_prices, ignore_index=True)
        
        #df.reset_index()
        #_now = list(range(0,len(df.index),1))
        _now = df.index
        print(_now)
        _data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=df,index=_now,columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Symbol'])
        #print(_data_frame)
        #_write_client.write(bucket.name, record=data_frame, data_frame_measurement_name='h2o_feet', data_frame_tag_columns=['location'])
        #return(_data_frame)
        write_api.write(influx_bucket, record=_data_frame, data_frame_measurement_name=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Symbol'],data_frame_tag_columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Symbol'])

    def return_stocks(self):
        return(self.stock_prices)

def main():
    s=Stocks()
    #set = s.return_stocks()
    s.write_db()
    
    """
    Prepare data
    """

    """
    Query: using Table structure
    """
    #query_api = client.query_api()
    #tables = query_api.query('from(bucket:"local") |> range(start: -1y)')

    #for table in tables:
        #print(table)
        #for record in table.records:
            #print(record.values)
    
    #result = client.query_api().query(org=influx_org, query=query)
    #results = []
    #for table in result:
        #for record in table.records:
            #results.append((record.get_field(), record.get_value()))

    #print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It was suggested that the executor multi processing might be causing the issue... but I get the same error even if I use a simple for loop for downloading stocks

```
   def __init__(self, db="stocks", stocks_file="stocks.json"):
        self.stocks=None
        self.db=db
        self.stock_prices = list()
        #column_names = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Dividends", "Stock Splits", "Symbol"]

        #df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)        
        #self.load_stocks_from_json(stocks_file)
        self.stocks=symbols
        for i in self.stocks:
            stock = self.dl_stocks(i)
            self.stock_prices.append(stock)
        
        #with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            #for out1 in executor.map(self.dl_stocks, self.stocks):            
                #self.stock_prices.append(out1)
```

Answer (score -2):

`self.stock_prices` is the output of a concurrent pool.  Those values won't exist until the processes complete and send back their results.  You aren't waiting for them.  Do you REALLY need those to run concurrently?  And why as separate processes, as opposed to threads?

In any case, I recommend you get this working without concurrent to begin with.  Once you have things working, then you can decide whether it runs fast enough or not.  If you do switch back to concurrent, you'll have to use .wait or .as_completed or .result to wait for the actual results.

Comment: I plan on scaling up,  parallel processing is a hard requirement. The fact i run the write function afterwards... I thought the parallel job would be done. Is that what the issue is? Does python do some sort of inventory check (of indexs) before the parallel process finishes? I could try to remove the parallel part and see if that resolves my issue

Comment: I made a simple for loop and got the exact same error (going to edit the original post to reflect that)